# Object reference not set to an instance of an object for loading User controls in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

my code is

```
Public Function resload()
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionrms").ConnectionString) ''line 18
    Dim comm As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand()
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    conn.Open()
    comm = New MySqlCommand("Select distinct name from restaurant", conn)
    dr = comm.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read() <> Nothing
        headresnamecombo.Items.Add(dr(0).ToString())
    End While
    dr.Close()
    headresnamecombo.SelectedIndex = 0
    conn.Close()
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

My Error

> > at Rest.billingBody.resload() in C:\Users\Azinova7\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Rest\Rest\billingBody.vb:line 18
> >
> > at Rest.billingBody.billingBody_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Azinova7\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Rest\Rest\billingBody.vb:line 229
> >
> > at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
> >
> > at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnCreateControl()
> >
> > at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
> >
> > at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
> >
> > at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
> >
> > at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
> >
> > at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.DesignerControlCollection.Add(Control c)

after that all is same connection codes

Comment: i code that line above see that in mysqlconnection object creation

Comment: First problem: `dr.Read` returns a Boolean, so you should just have `While dr.Read()`. You should also use `Using` statements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect that this is the problem:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionrms").ConnectionString
```

I suspect you don't have a connection string named "connectionrms" in your configuration.

The [`ConnectionStringSettingsCollection` indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6t3b6f3.aspx) will return `Nothing` if the given connection string isn't found.

That's only one problem with your code though. Additionally, you should be using `Using` statements for the connection and reader, and your `While` loop condition should just be `While dr.Read()`. Oh, and I'd declare variables at the point of first use rather than declaring everything at the top.

Comment: i had to write that connectionrms in app.config file    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionrms" connectionString="database=rms;server=localhost;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=XXXXX"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: @raja: Then I suspect that for whatever reason, it's not picking up your configuration. Try extracting the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connectionrms")` part into a separate variable first - I suspect you'll find the value is `Nothing`.

Comment: it's working normal window form in before, once i convert to user control i got this error